# Phaser 2 How can i use Animation with Phaser.sprite.call

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

How can I use animations with `Phaser` when I'm using `Phaser.Sprite.call`? Phaser is giving me the error:

```
phaser.min.js:19 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
    at new c.Animation (phaser.min.js:19)
```

I Googled so long for a solution but didn't find anything.

Here is my code:

```
var Enemy = function(game, x, y) {
    Phaser.Sprite.call(this, game, x,y,'Enemy');
    game.physics.enable(this, Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
    this.enableBody = true;
    this.body.gravity.y = 400;
    var walk = this.animations.add('walk');
    this.animations.play('walk', 4, true);
    this.anchor.setTo(0.5, 0.5);
    this.scale.setTo(0.15);
    this.body.velocity.x = -60;
    this.health = 4;
    this.maxHealth = 4;
}
Enemy.prototype = Object.create(Phaser.Sprite.prototype);
Enemy.prototype.constructor = Enemy;
```

Comment: What version of Phaser are you using? How are you adding the sprite to your game? With a slightly older version of Phaser 2 CE this seems to work fine when I try your code.

Comment: Im using Phaser v2.6.2 and im adding my sprite by using the key in Phaser.Sprite.call(this, game, x ,y, "key"). I did preload it first but nothing helps.

Comment: Sorry, I meant how are you adding your Enemy to the your game. Updated my test to 2.6.2 and your code seems to be working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/strivinglife/6vvyyybt/25/ Perhaps there's something else going? If you comment out the animations bit does it otherwise work as expected?

Comment: When i comment out the animations thing it works perfectly. Im adding my Enemys just by creating a new Enemy() and adding it to my enemys group.        this.enemys.add(new Enemy(this, this.game.width, 510));